# Restrict update to a field

Tags: validation-rule, validation

If a particular user updates the field only that specific user can edit the field further. Any restriction shouldn't be there for the initial population of data. How can I use the validation rule here, or is there any better solution to this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it only one field in question or all the fields ? If its only one field in question then you can capture the person who updated it and store it in a field and then use it in your validation formula.

Answer (score 0):

this is not something that is suppported out of the box, if the user populating the field is always the owner you can check in your validation rule when this field is being updated it is being done by the record owner.
otherwise if this user does not have to be the record owner you would need store the userid in another field as well and have a before save flow populate this field with the userid the moment your field is getting populated.

to avoid issues in the future you might also consider adding a bypass mechanism in case records get transferred or certain users get deactivated

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gilhil 's answer ...

If you have field history tracking on the field(s) in question, then ...

You could write an Apex Trigger (V58) or Flow ([V59 with custom errors](https://unofficialsf.com/sneak-preview-flow-in-winter-24/)) that

- queried the xxxHistory records looking for changes made to field(s) in question
- comparing the running user's ID against the userId on the xxxHistory record
- For triggers, use the sobject `addError(msg)` ; for flows, configure the custom error message element

**Caveats**

- Track field history limited to 20 fields unless you have Shield (60 fields) per object

**V59 preview of Flow Custom Errors**

[image]